# Borland C++ Builder 6 resize output executable to fit screen

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-6

In Borland C++ Builder 6 is it possible to customize the resolution of the output executable to fit any screen?

I built an executable at my laptop (1366x768) but I want to use it at another computer with lower resolution.

The reason I want to do that is because the destination computer has smaller touchscreen and I don't want to use scroll-bars.

Answer (score 1):

You should design your UI with a smaller resolution in mind to begin with and then design it to stretch to higher resolutions when needed.  You are trying to do the opposite, which won't work as well.  It is easier to stretch a UI than to shrink it.  With that said, the `Anchors` and `Constraints` properties on individual controls, and the `Scaled` property on Forms, are your friends, you should use them if you are not already.  `Anchors` in particular, because it allows you to stretch and shrink a Form while maintaining the relative layout of its controls.